# Access the Vertex Tool (Current Layer)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Since QGIS 3, there are two vertex tools: current layer and new: all layers. Normally I was able to access all actions with the code below. But now I can't find and activate the vertex tool (current layer). Even not by searching its caption! I have no idea how an action could be added which "does not exist". Any ideas?

```
def findAction(objName):
    try:
        toolbars = iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QToolBar)
        for toolbar in toolbars:
            for action in toolbar.actions():
                if isinstance(action, QWidgetAction):
                    if action.defaultWidget() and action.defaultWidget().actions():
                        dwa = action.defaultWidget().actions()
                        for a in dwa:
                            if IsSearchedAction(a,objName):
                                print ("a",a.objectName())
                                return a
                else:
                    if IsSearchedAction(action, objName): 
                        print ("action",action.objectName())
                        return action
        menubar = iface.mainWindow().menuBar()
        for action in menubar.actions():
            if action.menu():
                for action in action.menu().actions():
                    print("menu")
                    if action.menu():
                        for a in action.menu().actions():
                            if IsSearchedAction(a, objName): return a
                    else:
                        if IsSearchedAction(action, objName): return action
            else:
                if IsSearchedAction(action, objName): return action
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)

def IsSearchedAction(action, objname):
    objname = objname.lower()
    caption = action.text()
    caption = caption.replace("&", "")
    caption = caption.replace(".", "")
    caption = caption.strip()
    caption= caption.lower()
    return action.objectName().lower() == objname or caption == objname

print (iface.mapCanvas().mapTool().action().objectName())
action ="mActionVertexToolActiveLayer"
action ="mActionMeasure"
action ="mActionSelectFeatures"
action ="mActionVertexToolActiveLayer"#not found
print(findAction(action))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def findActionByObjectName(objname):
    try:
        toolbars = iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QToolBar)
        for toolbar in toolbars:
            for action in toolbar.actions():
                if action.objectName():
                   if action.objectName().lower() == objname.lower(): return action
                if action.actionGroup() is not None:
                    for a in action.actionGroup().actions():
                        if a.objectName():
                            if a.objectName().lower() == objname.lower(): return a
        menubar = iface.mainWindow().menuBar()
        for action in menubar.actions():
            if action.menu():
                for action in action.menu().actions():
                    if action.menu():
                        for a in action.menu().actions():
                            if a.objectName():
                                if a.objectName().lower() == objname.lower(): return a
                    else:
                        if action.objectName():
                            if action.objectName().lower() == objname.lower(): return action
            else:
                if action.objectName():
                    if action.objectName().lower() == objname.lower(): return action
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def findActionByLabel(label):
    try:
        label = label.lower()
        toolbars = iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QToolBar)
        for toolbar in toolbars:
            for action in toolbar.actions():
                if action.text():
                   if action.text().lower() == label: return action
                if action.actionGroup() is not None:
                    for a in action.actionGroup().actions():
                        if a.text():
                            if a.text().lower() == label: return a
        menubar = iface.mainWindow().menuBar()
        for action in menubar.actions():
            if action.menu():
                for action in action.menu().actions():
                    if action.menu():
                        for a in action.menu().actions():
                            if a.text():
                                if a.text().lower() == label: return a
                    else:
                        if action.text():
                            if action.text().lower() == label: return action
            else:
                if action.text():
                    if action.text().lower() == label: return action
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

actions = ["mActionVertexToolActiveLayer","mActionMeasureArea","mActionSelectFeatures","mActionVertexToolActiveLayer","X", "Enable Tracing","EnableTracingAction"]
for action in actions:
    found =findActionByObjectName(action)
    if found:
        print ("objectName:",found.objectName())
    else:
        found = findActionByLabel(action)
        print ("===")
        if found:
            print (found.text(),found)
            if found.objectName():
                print (found.text(),"/",found.objectName())
        else:
            print ("NOT FOUND:",action)
        print ("===")
```