# In QGIS, accessing and modifying via Python the polygon vertices manually selected via Vertex Tool

Tags: pyqgis, vertices

Working with QGIS 3.28, I am trying to find out how could one use Python to access and modify the vertices of a polygon that were selected manually (via mouse) using the Vertex Tool.

Despite all my searches throughout Stackexchange question, the QGIS code base, the [PyQGIS basic reference material](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/pdf/en/QGIS-testing-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf) and the [PyQGIS API docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.8/search.html?q=%22Vertex%20Tool%22&check_keywords=yes&area=default), I could not find any mention to whether and how this is possible. One of the rare mentions to more-or-less interfacing with Vertex Tools pro-grammatically is: [Access the Vertex Tool (Current Layer)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310429/access-the-vertex-tool-current-layer). But that one is simply about finding and activating the Vertex Tools programmatically.

Considering that the Vertex Tool already shows a table with coordinates of vertices (including a highlighting of selected vertices) that allows one to edit them, I would imagine that accessing and modifying them via Python is possible and certainly extremely useful. But I see no mentions to how this can be done anywhere.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 7):

Interesting question. It's certainly possible, though to be honest, I'm not sure there's a strong use-case. It's a bit hacky, but you can do it like this. Once you activate the vertex tool, right-click an editable feature to open the Vertex Editor dock widget and select a row in the table to highlight a vertex, you need to programmatically access the `QTableView` object which displays the table of feature vertices. Once you do that, we can use PyQt code to edit the data in a selected row.

Rough but working code snippet:

```py
v_editor = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'VertexEditor')
vert_tbl = v_editor.findChildren(QTableView)[0]
sel_model = vert_tbl.selectionModel()
selected_row = sel_model.selectedRows()[0].row()
x_index = vert_tbl.model().index(selected_row, 0)
y_index = vert_tbl.model().index(selected_row, 1)
vert_x = vert_tbl.model().data(x_index)
vert_y = vert_tbl.model().data(y_index)
print(vert_x)
print(vert_y)
new_x = 128.505273
new_y = -12.034135
vert_tbl.model().setData(x_index, new_x)
vert_tbl.model().setData(y_index, new_y)
```

Short screencast of demo results (apologies for the poor quality):

[image]